# Is there an algorithm to share parts of strings?

Tags: strings, substrings, string-matching

Let's say that we have the strings `Hello, World`, `Hello` and `World`. The algorithm I am thinking of would create an immutable buffer that contains `Hello, World` and the previous three would then become references or slices of that one like `buf[0,11], buf[0,4], buf[7,11]`.

A way to implement this algorithm would be to compare all new strings to the existing buffer and reuse it if possible or append the new string if that's not the case. This would be very slow, but it should work. However, it does not efficiently handle a case like `Hey, Hello` because it would either append it to the buffer, adding `Hello` again, or add `Hey,` to the beginning and update all the indices.

If saving space is the optimal solution, then the final buffer would be `Hey, Hello, World`.

**Is there any algorithm that does something similar?**

I have read about ropes, and read [this article](https://itnext.io/string-similarity-the-basic-know-your-algorithms-guide-3de3d7346227), but I do not see how these would help.

**EDIT**: this is indeed a shortest superstring problem, but the implementations I have found ([1](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/shortest-superstring-problem/),[2](https://leetcode.com/problems/find-the-shortest-superstring/)) assume that no string in the array could be a substring of another one, which is not the case here.

Comment: @xskxzr they are very, very similar, but this one has the twist that there can be substrings of other strings in the array

Comment: If you just need references to an array, use a language or library with support for slices-as-views

Comment: The issue was constructing a superstring from all those strings. The slice part is already implemented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a **shortest superstring problem** and not allowing internal substrings is just an implementation detail.